# How do I calculate the runtime of my code in c

Tags: c

I saw many posts, but I wanted to reopen it because I could not understand the results.

I'm interested in the insertion sort algorithm. I want to get the runtime of the code in different array sizes (array size: like 1000 or 10,000) in a list in sequential and reverse order (for worst case).

Here my c code

Array size  10k. and I used sleep(2) because otherwise my result always 0.

Now my results are constantly changing such as. 2.003000 seconds,2.004700 seconds,2.009500 seconds,2.007000 seconds

How can I handle this and determine the duration for a best-case 10k array.

Also here all code https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jVHVPorelq-XCd9nrNx97KloXYEoX2l/view?usp=sharing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>       // for clock_t, clock(), CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include <unistd.h>     // for sleep()

// main function to find the execution time of a C program
int main()
{
    // to store the execution time of code
    double time_spent = 0.0;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, ................, 9997, 9998, 9999, 10000};
     
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    

    
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
 
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
          greater than key, to one position ahead
          of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    
    
    sleep(2);

    clock_t end = clock();

    // calculate elapsed time by finding difference (end - begin) and
    // dividing the difference by CLOCKS_PER_SEC to convert to seconds
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to profile your code (with precise timing information) - or are you asking how to determine its runtime complexity? Those are two separate topics.

Comment: Run it few thousands of times on *different* 10k arrays and take average

Comment: Note that the average difference between 2.003000, 2.004700, 2.009500 and 2.007000 is already less than half a percent.  Better timing precision is most likely not going to matter.

Comment: Your code does nothing _obeservable_. Any good compiler [will optimize](https://godbolt.org/z/j7cP6PoKn) your code to just `int main() { clock(); sleep(2); clock(); printf(....) }` removing _all_ the code you are trying to profile. Anyway, research "how to profile code". Also, did you wrote all numbers between `1` and `10000` in your source? ... why not use a loop?

Comment: @Dai I want to create arrays of different sizes for best and worst cases and observe the time complexity.

Comment: Using `sleep(2)` is not helpful. As already stated, your problem is that the result of your calculations are not observable, so your compiler is probably optimizing them away.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Without using sleep (2) the result is always 0. How can I solve this. I am using devc ++.

Comment: @thekavak: You can force your compiler to actually perform the calculations by doing something observable with the results, such as adding up all elements of the result array and printing the sum. You can do this after printing the elapsed time, so that the adding up of all elements does not interfere with your timing measurements.